# Trying to get COUNT(*) from custom content type with EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, database

How can I retrieve the 'count(*)' from a query in drupal 7?  The query needs to include a custom content type and a custom field.

Notes

- Custom Content Type: **employees**
- Custom Field Name: **field_employees_email**
- As a note, I'm looking to add

  WHERE field_employees_email = 'example@example.com'

to the query...

So far, I have something like:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;    

$result = $query
     ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
     ->propertyCondition('status', 1) // Getting published nodes only.
     ->propertyCondition('type', 'employees') //Getting 'employees' type only.
     // How do I include custom field as part of query?
     ->execute();
```

Also, is there an easier way than

```
$total = count($result);
```

to return the COUNT(*) from the query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [EntityFieldQuery::count()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3acount/7), as reported in the documentation for [EntityFieldQuery::execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3aexecute/7).

> [The result is] Either a number if `count()` was called or an array of associative arrays of stub entities.

The code you should use is similar to the following one:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;

$count = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'employees')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1) // Getting published nodes only.
  ->count()
  ->execute();
```

To filter the result by the content type, you need to use [EntityFieldQuery::entityCondition('bundle', $content_type)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3aentityCondition/7).
For conditions on fields, you should use [EntityFieldQuery::fieldCondition()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3afieldCondition/7).

Comment: Thank you @kiamlaluno  fieldCondition is what I was looking for.  This post was pretty helpful for anyone else searching as well: http://commerceguys.com/blog/checking-out-entityfieldquery