# How to count the number of posts by a author?

Tags: views

I have created a view with table settings. I would like to display the name of the author and the total number of posts that he has created. I have used relations to get the author name but I don't see any fields related to count the number of posts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See very similar question (with answer that goes through Views aggregation steps) at [User list view showing total nodes created for each user](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34204/user-list-view-showing-total-nodes-created-for-each-user)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using D7 I think you will have to enable `aggregation` for you view, and then set the `group by` for you field (`Content:nid` for example) to `Count`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply krister. May i know how to enable aggregation? the only thing i can see in my modules page is a aggregator.

Comment: Under /admin/structure/views/view/your_view you click the `Advanced` tab at the top-right and the you'll find `Use Aggregation` under `Others`.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! you have finally solved my 4 hrs battle:):) thank u so much.

Comment: FYI: [Count of nodes by type](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/15875/226) is a very similar question, and I posted a step-by-step instruction for Views with aggregation, as well as an export of such a view.

Comment: Wow amazing work marcvangend!!! thanks a lot for such a usefull explaination. Finally i got every thing working:)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views)/Drupal are you using?

The [User Stats](http://drupal.org/project/user_stats) module may work for what you need.

Comment: I tried this module. But i don know how to use this in views.