# How to count the number of posts by a author? D8

Tags: views, 8

I [see how to do this in D7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/how-to-count-the-number-of-posts-by-a-author). I tried to do something similar in D8.

I tried using Entity instead of Content because there is no content:nid option in D8 my view looked like this

```
(author) COUNT(File Usage: Entity ID) (Count by User) | Aggregation settings
```

but my results where all 0

Comment: The code snippet should give you an idea about why you have 0 results. It is counting *file usage* not node author.

Comment: Node author was not an option

Comment: The "Authored by" label is used to designate the content author as a field. I just confirmed this on simplytest.me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of posts by a author?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/how-to-count-the-number-of-posts-by-a-author)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 on how to accomplish this.

From a default Content view:

1. Add the "Content: Authored By" field to the view.
2. Click "Use Aggregation" and change to yes.
3. Click "Aggregation Settings" to the right of "Content: Title".
4. Change to COUNT and Entity ID respectively.

View export:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - node
    - user
id: content_with_author_count
label: 'Content with author count'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content'
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: none
        options:
          offset: 0
      style:
        type: default
        options:
          grouping: {  }
          row_class: ''
          default_row_class: true
          uses_fields: false
      row:
        type: fields
        options:
          inline: {  }
          separator: ''
          hide_empty: false
          default_field_elements: true
      fields:
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          relationship: none
          group_type: count
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          settings:
            link_to_entity: false
          group_column: entity_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: title
          plugin_id: field
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: node_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: target_id
          type: author
          settings:
            link: 0
          group_column: target_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          set_precision: false
          precision: 0
          decimal: .
          format_plural: 0
          format_plural_string: "1\x03@count"
          prefix: ''
          suffix: ''
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: field
      filters:
        status:
          value: true
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
          id: status
          expose:
            operator: ''
          group: 1
      sorts: {  }
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships:
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: node_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: author
          required: true
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: standard
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
      group_by: true
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
```

Comment: Do not forget to check "SORT CRITERIA"
There should be empty. By default Drupal adds sorting.

Answer (score -3):

Drupal 8 is new and many things still unclear. It will take some time before sufficient information will be available. If you need a quick solution I recommend to inspect database tables and get the needed information using db_query and SQL select. Should be straightforward.

Comment: Still 2 years to go before people start to have an idea as to how to do things in Dtupal 8. Votes down? Well as to SQL, it is much faster to do things using db_query and SQL than using core functions. Why to stress the server for basic needs?

Comment: I voted this down, because (1) `db_query()` is deprecated in Drupal 8 in favor of either the injected database connection or the one from the static service wrapper (2) this question is specifically about views, so I don't see how a custom query helps, and (3) it has been five months since Drupal 8.0.0, and I don't think is valid to say the database layer is unclear and there isn't sufficient information on it.  I'll also add (4) that it isn't recommended to query directly against database for entities; EFQ has been the recommendation since Drupal 7.