# Count results in Views using aggregation

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to count results (e.g. count the nodes of the content type x) in a view, using aggregation (not programmatically)?

Comment: Sure, just use aggregation and then select "count" for your "node id" field.

Comment: There is an identical Q&A at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/count-of-nodes-by-type, including a ready-to-use view export.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in Views 3 out of the box.
The idea is the same as in SQL aggregations. Lets see an example:

1. Edit your view and enable Views aggregations:
   [image: enable Views aggregations]
2. Remove default sort criteria.
3. Add fields “Content: Type” and “Content: Nid”:
   [image]
   Select COUNT function for Content: Nid:
   [image]

To see what happens just turn on checkbox “Show the SQL query” at global Views settings page.

```sql
SELECT node.type AS node_type, COUNT(node.nid) AS nid
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') ))
GROUP BY node_type
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

So, we are grouping nodes by node_type and calculating count for this groups.

Comment: I was stuck for couple of hours, then after reading your post I realized that I had default sorting there. Thanks @kalabro

Comment: So how is the count made available - is it a token variable and how can it be displayed?

Comment: Your reply is, of course, correct. However, I've been stuck when using Relationships with Entity References and Aggregation. It works fine if you build a block, but not if you make a Page. Weird stuff.

Answer (score 12):

Great answers here though your original question does not state what you are going to *do* with the count value. Presumably you want to display it?

If so, here's another solution:

Assuming that your View is already set up to filter by items of content type, then you can also add a header in the View and choose the "Global: Result summary" option and use the token variables provided in the text area.

Comment: To clarify, this extends the great solution provided by kalabro, to display a count.

Answer (score -2):

Just in case someone comes across this.

I used the [Views Date Format SQL](http://drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql) to format the date to the granularity.

> The Views Date Format SQL module allows to format date fields using
>   SQL. This enables group aggregation for date fields using the choosen
>   granularity.
>
> The core functionality is to remove the date formatting from render()
>   and put it in query(). I.e. format date values using SQL's DATE_FORMAT
>   rather than PHP's format_date.
>
> This is achieved by assigning a new default handler to node 'created'
>   and 'changed' date fields. This handler extends and overrides views's
>   build in views_handler_field_date.

Worked right out of the box - easy as!