# Views: Get total results

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to get a total count of the results using Views.  Looking at this link, [Count results in Views using aggregation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20705/count-results-in-views-using-aggregation), I use aggregation, but Views counts each row as 1.  For example, this is what I get:

```
TITLE         Results
"A title"     1
"A title2"    1
"A title3"    1
etc...
```

I want it to be

```
Title
"A title"
"A title2"
"A title3"

Results: 3
```

Any way to do this in Views?  If not, is there a way I can weak the current Views SQL or its output instead of having to write my own module and SQL query from scratch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a *Global: Result summary* field to the footer. There is no need to turn on aggregation.

Comment: I think you mean *Global: Result summary* not *"Global: results"* in list of things offered in Footer. So, in the View edit screen, select 'Add Footer' (middle column of the settings) then choose *Global: Result summary* And then choose from the various @ prefixed variables regarding what you'd like to display.