# How to count nodes per content type in views D7

Tags: views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count of nodes by type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/count-of-nodes-by-type)

I'm building a views block for the current/logged in user. In this block, I'd like to have a view that shows counts nodes related with content types. Here's an example:

(Submitted) blogs: 5
 articles: 3
 polls: 2

Comment: You can find the answer for this question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20705/count-results-in-views-using-aggregation

Comment: You can take help from the answer of the question [here..][1]

Thanks

  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/count-of-nodes-by-type