# Setup a Tabular View to Include Total Count of Nodes

Tags: views

Need to create a Views page displaying tabular data.

Fields I need are:

1) Total count of nodes created from Content Type A, filtered by US State, and the 2) second field is the total count of nodes created from Content Type B, filtered by US state.

Answer (score 0):

Create two block display of a view. The view should contain All content types. displays are `block_1` and `block_2`. set `content type:Content Type A` as filter criteria for `block_1` and `content type:Content Type B` as filter criteria for `block_2`. so `block_1` and `block_2` shows all of the nodes of `A` and `B`. This [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20705/count-results-in-views-using-aggregation) shows how to count number of results. Now the following code

```
<?php print views_embed_view('YourView','block_1');?>
<?php print views_embed_view('YourView','block_2');?>
```

outputs the number of results and you can format them in any way you want.