# How to find number of assigned content to all user

Tags: views

I have book content type, where i attached user entity reference fied.
In which i can select user to assign the books.

How can i find list of users and its number of assigned books.

Thanks

Comment: You can create a view for that.

Comment: can you tell me the steps.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to add the entity reference field using relationship to the view. Then use aggregation to find the count.

Refer https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/entity-reference-views/ on how to create view using entity reference field. 
To find the count, you can use aggregation. For using aggregation you can refer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/31542/48290.