# how to count results in a Calendar view?

Tags: views, datetime

I enable [the calendar module](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar), then "Add view from template" on /admin/structure/views/add-template, but I cannot count nodes published at the same day in the month view by following [this tutorial](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20705/count-results-in-views-using-aggregation).
I want events occurred in the same day can be counted like "3 events occurred" other than the original output in the red box, and the counted field can be rewritten. 
[image]

I tried aggregation feature of views, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I get it working.
After I turn on View's setting "Show the SQL query", I notice there is an unnecessary GROUP BY field "nid" in the Calendar view, then I unset this field in a hook_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) as below:

```
if ($query->hasTag('views_' . $view_name)) {
    $fields =& $query->getGroupBy();
    unset($fields['nid']);
}
```

Comment: fishfree, please add detalis on how you did manage to count results, i allready unset group by nid, but i cant go further, i tryed aggregation, no luck, i override every teamplate in month-calendar view and nothing.