# How to print how many nodes of a specific type a user has created?

Tags: 7, nodes, blocks, database

I'm making a block to be displayed on a node page that I want to display some information about the author of the node. I need to be able to show the number nodes of different types that the author has created. Any suggestions? I found [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/count-of-nodes-by-type) which gets me halfway there, but I need to be able to filter it by only the node authors content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to extend the query from the other question you linked to and add the user id as an extra parameter:

```
function yourtheme_get_node_count($content_type) {
  $query = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM {node} n
    WHERE n.type = :type
    AND n.uid = :uid";

  // Get the node object for the current page.
  $node = menu_get_object();

  $params = array(':type' => $content_type, ':uid' => $node->uid);
  $amount = db_query($query, $params)->fetchField();

  return $amount;
}
```

Be sure to only call this on a node page as `menu_get_object()` will only return a node object when you're on such a page.