# How to display the number of contents of a node?

Tags: nodes, log-messages

We have a property site that we use to categorize our listings. I would like to know how to make each category show the number of content it has e.g. Sales(45), Lettings(20), etc.

Any help about how to do this? I am new to Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

could you add some details to your question that will tell us WHERE you want to see these counts?   Is it in a page template? A view? A block?  The answer will change depending.

In the meantime, please look at this:
[Count of nodes by type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/count-of-nodes-by-type)

Answer (score 0):

This question is exactly what the purpose is of one of the [Out-of-the-box examples](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426921) that you get after install/enable of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, and without any additional configuration.

By doing so, a new view is added to your site. Here are some more details about it, quoted from the linked page above (to which I added some formatting here):

> You can see the charts created via this new view in your own site by
>   navigating to charts/examples or by using a menu link with a title
>   like Charts examples. After doing so, a page is shown with 2 sub-menu
>   tabs:
>
> - the first tab is titled **Built-in examples** (this example is used to
>     showcase [Using the Charts API](https://www.drupal.org/node/233916)).
> - the second tab is titled **Views
>     example**, and is what is created from the new view created during the
>     installation of the charts module. As an alternative to using this
>     tab, just navigate to charts/examples/views in your site. You should
>     then see a column chart and a pie chart, which are followed by a
>     tabular display also. ***Both charts and the table display contain data
>     about the total number of nodes for each of the available content
>     types.***

Visit the [Charts demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/charts/examples/views) for an online preview of of these out-of-the-box examples.

Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of this module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).