# Numbering the content list in drupal (as simple as it sound) - possible via the UI?

Tags: nodes

Went through the conf and the Drupalsite > Content page but couldn't find any where to number the list (or at least to get a nubmer of all contents of all entities and types - including Views, Panels, Webforms, ETC).

Would thank you for showing a simple way for numbering this list \ get a content-total number.

Here is the picture of my natural display of the content page... Thanks, Ben.

[image]

Comment: What would the numbers represent exactly (bearing in mind you can filter that list)? One option would probably be [Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views), it'll convert that page to a View which you can manipulate to provide totals/numbering etc

Comment: The number of items in relation to the filtering... Can you think of a lighter option than a module (Does the module makes everything automatic?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might be looking for number of nodes by content type (among other things). If that's the case then you may want to consider the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. It comes with a sample view that gives you both a tabular overview and a chart of these numbers.

The (accepted) answer to the question [Views and node count for taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms) contains another (views) based example.

The question [Count of nodes by type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/count-of-nodes-by-type) contains some code snippets that may help to write your custom module to calculate these counts.

If you don't want to install/enable the Charts module permanently, you may want to temporarely enable it to (eg) look at the view for the tabular format display, and then create a clone of that view to perfectly fit your needs (and then uninstall the Charts module again). Of course the "Views" module is yet another module. But it's rare to find a site that does not use the views module, so that's maybe an acceptable compromise to consider (you might have Views available already)?

Comment: Is there any non-modular way (maybe even adding something in the PHP template of a relevant core module?

Comment: I do have views installed and use it for several purposes... Is there maybe a simpler way even than views-based modules? Even a simple content pieces counter (with an option to filter entities\publish mode) could do the trick, I just don't want to counter manually.