# How to know how many nodes my website has?

Tags: 9

In `/admin/content` no specific number of nodes is available.

How to know how many nodes my website has, preferably [without installing a module](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount)?

I want to know how many nodes I have in general, [not of a specific content type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/count-of-nodes-by-type).

- I didn't find any native Drush command.
- I personally would prefer `Bash` or JavaScript over PHP to count if I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `/admin/content` list is just another view. You can configure that view and temporarily add a result summary widget plugin in the header, which you can configure to get the total (it's the thing you use to render the "Showing X of TOTAL").

Comment: Yep I picked "Result summary" in the header of the view. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use an entity query:

```
$count = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->accessCheck(FALSE)->count()->execute();
```

You can run this from a Bash shell with `drush ev "..."` or in an interactive PHP shell:

```
drush php
> \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->accessCheck(FALSE)->count()->execute();
= 123
```